# I can't get nested ifelse()-statement on data containing NA to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: r, if-statement

Reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(batch = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA),
          weight = c(1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA))

data$class <- ifelse((data$batch == 1 & data$weight == 0), 1,
                  ifelse((data$batch == 1 & data$weight == 1), 2,
                         ifelse((data$weight == 1), 4, 
                                ifelse((data$batch == 1 & is.na(data$weight)), 3, 0))))
```

The above works except for the last argument. I want those with "1" in the batch column and missing values in the weight column to be get class "3", but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could use case_when() instead:

```
data$class = case_when(
                      is.na(data$weight) & (data$batch == 1) ~ "3", 
                      data$weight == 1 ~ "4",
                      (data$batch == 1 & data$weight == 1) ~ "2",
                      (data$batch == 1 & data$weight == 0) ~ "1")
```

However, it would still be interesting to know *why* ifelse() doesn't work in this instance?

Comment: Each case is evaluated, so if you have NAs and those aren't evaluated first, you'll get NA for the first test and the rest won't matter. See `ifelse(NA, "true", "false")` produces `NA` but your logic relies on the evaluation continuing down the "false" path. The reason your `case_when` works is that you have adjusted the test order to account for NAs.